# Cannot center link in AngularJS ui-view

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a link that looks like a button that needs to be at the center of the page horizontally.

This is the link:

```
<a href="#top" target="_self" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Return to Top</a>
```

I have tried:

```
style = "margin: 0 auto"
style = "text-align: center"
class="btn btn-info btn-xs center-block"
```

Nothing works. Is it because my ui-view is set like so this?

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

What should I do?

Comment: To work with `margin: 0 auto` you need to set a fixed `width` to the link. If it's not an option, `text-align: center` needs to be applied to `<ui-view></ui-view>` and maybe `width: 100%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just wrap your button inside a div and add the text-center class to the div as follows:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <a href="#top" target="_self" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Return to Top</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi jme11, The problem here is actually not just centering the button. The main issue here is... no width to center the button within. Have a look at my fiddle. and read the other answer by Imgonzalves.

Comment: @AngularJR - actually, a div is a block level element.  So, it will automatically takes 100% of the parent element width.  The button is an inline element, so when you wrap it in a div and add the text-center class, which just add text-align: center, the button is centered.  Test it if you like.

Comment: Hi, I understand that, but this person is not using `div` element here. Yes, if using your `div` example will do that . But this example is using this `<ui-view></ui-view>`. Have another look at the fiddle second block.

Answer (score 1):

**axc**, Hi there. Along the line of what **Imgonzalves** has said.
You need to give some width to **center** something within.

Have a look at this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkb458yc/)**.
The top block you will see the button is centered.
Using the Bootstrap class `text-center` which is placed in the parent and then it will center all text within that div and ones within.
The parent has width because it uses the class `col-md-10`.

The second orange block in this demo shows you what you were trying to do.

Hope this shows you that you need to give a div some width to center the button within.

Comment: Thank you but shouldn't center-block automatically put the button in the middle of the page? @AngularJR

Comment: Hi, Yes and No in this case. As you see in my fiddle and the second orange block I give `<ui-view class="block2 text-center">` a color redorange and give it some left/right padding so we can see where this block is. But this block is to the left and only the width of the button plus the padding. Because  `<ui-view>` does not inherit the full width of the parent. This is why we are saying in this case, the `</ui-view>` needs to be given a width. At the moment the width is only the width of the button. Does that help to see the difference here.

Comment: @AngularJR you have to understand that the browser basically ignores any non-standard tags it encounters.  That's what the [HTML 2](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_4.html#SEC4.2.1) spec tells them to do.  This is why, if we want support for [non-standard browsers like IE8](http://tatiyants.com/how-to-get-ie8-to-support-html5-tags-and-web-fonts/), we have to either create CSS rules for them ourself or use directives as attributes only.  In this case, we treat the `ui-view` directive as though its not there and then the inheritance comes from the col-md-10 div.